# How to instruct exoplayer to pause at a certain position in advance?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am geting a HLS stream video which has to be played part by part and between the parts I should show some animations.

For example the first part has 19.2 seconds duration. What will be the best way to schedule `exoplayer` to pause after exact duration ?

Currently I am using a handler to pause after exact duration, which of course is not a good solution, because we may have case when video is not loaded.

Comment: It looks like you're doing good. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2828

Comment: @Korcholis so posting infinite handler and checking currentPosition is ok ?

Comment: Hah, I didn't explicitly say that. As you say, there are issues, definitely, but even the exoplayer devs say it's much better to do this check aside from the listener system, probably to avoid too much stress (imagine getting a listener every millisecond the video is playing)

Comment: Thx, and I didn't ask in ironic :))

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use ClippingMediaSource. Google it and see if it suits you.